# bower installed but doesn't install package

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

I am looking to use yeoman with the generator-marionette.

- I am on debian 7
- I have installed nodejs v0.10.28 and npm 1.4.9. and
  grunt-cli (global)
- then i installed bower : `npm install -g bower`
- `bower help` works fine
- `bower install` gives Nothing (no packages installation, no error message) (bower.json exists)
- `bower install jquery` gives the same result.

Does someone has an idea of what appends and a solution to solve this problem ?

Comment: Could you please copy-paste the exact result of that command(s)? Or does it just end without writing out anything?

Comment: Is your bower.json file well formatted? Here's its [spec](https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec)?